# How to Cycle only part of the frames in an animation

Tags: fcurves

How can I cycle only some key frames of an animation in graph editor?

Let's say I have an animation with 100 frames. When I apply cyclic F-Curve modifier, all the frames are made cyclic, i.e, after frame 100, frames 1-100 are again repeated and so on.

I want only the later part of the frames to be made cyclic, i.e, after frame 100, frames 75-100 should be repeated endlessly.

I have tried selecting only frames 75-100 and applying the modifier, but still it is applied on 1-100.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The cycles modifier takes **all** your keyframes for a property and loops them, it doesn't allow you to loop part of your animation. If you want just a part to be repeated, you can select all the related keyframes and duplicate them with `SHIFT+D` then `X` to slide them on the x axis. Then, you can repeat that as many times as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is with actions and the nonlinear animation editor.

- Create an action starting at frame 1 and do the animation you would do up to frame 75 inclusive.
- Push it down to the NLA
- Create a new action starting at frame 75.  Start it by keyframing everything that was keyframed at 75 in the first action.
- do the animation from frame 75 to frame 100.
- Push it down to the NLA.

In the NLA you will have a track that looks something like this:

[image: NLA showing the track with the two actions]

For my simple example, instead of 1-75, 75-100, I did 1-10, 10-20, so the actions aren't in the same places they'd be in your animation.

Select the second action, the one I called 'bounce' in my example, and open the side panel of the NLA (Shortcut <kbd>N</kbd> to toggle).  Select the *Strip* tab and open all of the panels. You'll see something like this:

[image: Strip side panel showing all of the settings.]

You can't set the repeat to infinite, but you can set it to a large enough number to cover your animation.  In my 250 frame example, I set it to 24:

[image: repeat set to 24]