Looping animation after the first animated scene
Completely new to Blender here. In fact, completely new to 3D modelling/animation and everything that has to do with it. And that makes it really hard for me to formulate this question, because all the terminology is new to me. But, i (think) i have created my first scene, at least done modelling, and i am ready to animate. Which made the modelling seem easy
The question at hand, is if there is any way to keep an animation going after the "main" animation? Like: Fram 1 (animation starts) -> Frame 250 (animation ends): but i want it to loop after Frame 250. Not the whole animation, just like the last 10 (or so) frames.
Only been doing this for 3 weeks, so please forgive me if the question seems dumb.

Look into the Cycles f-curve modifier. Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/242835/how-to-cycle-only-part-of-the-frames-in-an-animation and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57394/how-to-specify-frames-for-%D0%A1ycles-modifier-in-f-curve-editor

Hey @DuarteFarrajotaRamos!
"Cycles* f-curve modifier" is like reading mandarin (i'm Norwegian), i am really new to this But i'll check out the links you added, thank you so much!
